# get list of quarters between two dates (SQL)

Tags: sql-server

I would like to receive a list of quarters between given dates (startDate and EndDate parameter).

For example partial quarter dates:

```
StartDate : 2017-01-01
EndDate : 2017-06-15
Result : Q1 Q2
```

another sample :

```
StartDate : 2017-01-01
EndDate : 2017-06-30
Result : Q2
```

Comment: Can you please explain further? how only Q2 in second example?

Comment: it's exact quarter. quarter 1 : 2017-01-01 - 2017-31-03  , quarter 2 : 2017-04-01  2017-06-30

Comment: Is result a single string or N rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this, you would need to override the maximum recursion if you have a lot of quarters to list though:

```
DECLARE @start_date DATE = '20170101';
DECLARE @end_date DATE = '20170615';
WITH x AS (
    SELECT
        YEAR(@start_date) AS [year],
        DATEPART(QUARTER, @start_date) AS [quarter]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        CASE 
            WHEN [quarter] = 4 THEN [year] + 1
            ELSE [year]
        END AS [year],
        CASE
            WHEN [quarter] = 4 THEN 1
            ELSE [quarter] + 1 
        END AS [quarter]
    FROM
        x
    WHERE
        [year] <= YEAR(@end_date)
        AND [quarter] < DATEPART(QUARTER, @end_date))
SELECT * FROM x;
```

Comment: I get the same answer if I put either 20170615 or 20170630.  Then again, OP's requested output doesn't make sense to me either.

Comment: can this be accomplished without the key word "With"?

Comment: Yes, you could make a "numbers table", etc.  But you can't use recursion without using WITH (or if you can I can't see how).

Answer (score 1):

**If open to a TVF.** I'll often use a Table-Valued Function to return dynamic datetime ranges.

**Example - Rows**

```
Select *
      ,Qtr='Q'+DateName(QUARTER,RetVal)
 from [dbo].[tvf-Range-Date]('2017-01-01','2017-06-15','QQ',1)
```

**Returns**

```
RetSeq  RetVal      Qtr
1       2017-01-01  Q1
2       2017-04-01  Q2
```

**Example - Single String**

```
Select Qtr = Stuff((Select Distinct ' ' + 'Q'+DateName(QUARTER,RetVal) 
                     From  [dbo].[tvf-Range-Date]('2017-01-01','2017-06-15','QQ',1) 
                     For XML Path ('')),1,1,'')
```

**Returns**

```
Qtr
Q1 Q2
```

**The UDF if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-Range-Date] (@R1 datetime,@R2 datetime,@Part varchar(10),@Incr int)
Returns Table
Return (
    with cte0(M)   As (Select 1+Case @Part When 'YY' then DateDiff(YY,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'QQ' then DateDiff(QQ,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'MM' then DateDiff(MM,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'WK' then DateDiff(WK,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'DD' then DateDiff(DD,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'HH' then DateDiff(HH,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'MI' then DateDiff(MI,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'SS' then DateDiff(SS,@R1,@R2)/@Incr End),
         cte1(N)   As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
         cte2(N)   As (Select Top (Select M from cte0) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From cte1 a, cte1 b, cte1 c, cte1 d, cte1 e, cte1 f, cte1 g, cte1 h ),
         cte3(N,D) As (Select 0,@R1 Union All Select N,Case @Part When 'YY' then DateAdd(YY, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'QQ' then DateAdd(QQ, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'MM' then DateAdd(MM, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'WK' then DateAdd(WK, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'DD' then DateAdd(DD, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'HH' then DateAdd(HH, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'MI' then DateAdd(MI, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'SS' then DateAdd(SS, N*@Incr, @R1) End From cte2 )

    Select RetSeq = N+1
          ,RetVal = D 
     From  cte3,cte0 
     Where D<=@R2
)
/*
Max 100 million observations -- Date Parts YY QQ MM WK DD HH MI SS
Syntax:
Select * from [dbo].[tvf-Range-Date]('2016-10-01','2020-10-01','YY',1) 
Select * from [dbo].[tvf-Range-Date]('2016-01-01','2017-01-01','MM',1) 
Select * from [dbo].[tvf-Range-Date]('2017-01-01','2017-01-02','MI',15) 
*/
```